# The card clicked should be flip

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having 16 cards, I want to flip the card which I click. The code I have written is flipping the first card after click but it is not applicable for other cards. Please help me so that I can flip the card which I clicked.

HTML

```
<div class="scene">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__face card__face--front">front</div>
          <div class="card__face card__face--back">back</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

JS

```
var card = document.querySelector('.card');
    card.addEventListener('click', function() {
      card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
```

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll('.card')`

Comment: I have tried that but by doing that none of the cards is flipping.

Comment: You should change the event binding as well.Iterate over `card` list and addEventListener to all.

Comment: If you privice your css code for `.is-flipped` , i can create a working snippet.

Comment: .card.is-flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6dqnygex/)